# Why does RateLimiter allow only 1 transaction for a rate limit of 2 TPS?

Tags: java, guava, rate-limiting

RateLimiter configured for a rate of 2 TPS only allows 1st request and throttles 2nd Request.

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.*;

class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        RateLimiter rl = RateLimiter.create(2);
        System.out.println(rl.getRate());
        System.out.println(rl.tryAcquire());
        System.out.println(rl.tryAcquire());
        System.out.println(rl.tryAcquire());
   }

}
```

Output:

```
2.0
true
false
false
```

I expect that since rate is configured to 2 TPS, it would allow first *two* requests and not just the first one. Why does this happen?

Using guava-27.0-jre.jar.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As far as I remember, the requests allowed are spread evenly over the second and one will in this case be allowed per 500ms. You’re requesting with much lower intervals.

Comment: Verified! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Smooth distribution

> A RateLimiter is defined primarily by the rate at which permits are issued. Absent additional configuration, permits will be distributed at a fixed rate, defined in terms of permits per second. Permits will be distributed smoothly, with the delay between individual permits being adjusted to ensure that the configured rate is maintained.

> It is possible to configure a RateLimiter to have a warmup period during which time the permits issued each second steadily increases until it hits the stable rate.

Ref: [Rate Limiter](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html)

The configured rate is distributed evenly across the interval. (more like a sliding window)